# BE14NU40 Blue Ray burner burns one disc and now won't burn any more on Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, burning, blu-ray

My LG Blue Ray BE14NU40 burner burned a single disc on a fresh installation of Windows 10 Pro.  Now when I put a blank disk in the drive, it does not display the Auto Play "Burn a Disc" dialog.  I can still read existing Blue Ray discs on it, but I can't burn anything.

If I click on the drive I get `Windows can't read the disc in drive <drive-letter>:\` `Make sure that the disc uses a format that Windows recognizes.  If the disc is unformatted, you need to format it before using it.`

Comment: I looked in the system section of the Event Log, but I didn't find anything related to this.

Comment: I occasionally have this problem (same error message) on Windows after burning a CD using iTunes. I burn a CD (it auto ejects when the burn is finished) and the same CD cannot be read immediately afterwards. It is fixed by a restart in my case.

Comment: @DavidPostill I already restarted it.

Comment: I ended up using imgburn, and that worked just fine; finalized the new BD-R and everything.  Sad that we have to turn to 3rd parties for something that should "just work" in a Windows OS.